# How to add sidebars in footer of the wordpress(version 3.0) theme?

Tags: wordpress-theming

I want to add sidebars or widgets to wordpress theme, I tried many tuts online but they failed because they are to outdated. My website link is here

http://lifetothebrim.com

```
 I want to add sidebar in three column layout.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to add a sidebar in the footer of a WordPress theme

---

#### Step 1.

Register your sidebars in functions.php

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer Widgets Left',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Footer Widgets Center',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
        ));


if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Footer Widgets Right',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
        ));
```

#### Step 2.

Create a template file and name it **sidebar-footer.php** and include the call to your sidebar

```
<div class="footer-left>

    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widgets Left') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>

</div>
<div class="footer-center">

   <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widgets Center') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>

</div>

<div class="footer-right">

   <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widgets Right') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

<del>Note: for styling purposes you should wrap the above function call in a div</del>

I broke it into 3 widget areas for you with the css clases "footer-left", "footer-center", and "footer-right"

You will have to add the styles to display them in your css.

Example: clear any floated divs that come before this.

```
.footer-left {width:300px;float:left;} .footer-center {width:300px;float:left;} .footer-right {width:300px;float:left;}
```

make sure the next div clears:both

#### Step 3.

In your footer.php or at the bottom of any of your templates add

```
<?php get_sidebar('footer'); ?>
```

Comment: but it didnt worked, I downloaded another theme from same designer this new theme have sidebars in footer below is the code

Comment: <div id="one-col">
  <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar One Column') ) : ?> 
  <?php endif; ?>
 </div> <!-- end #first-col -->
 
 <div id="first-col">
  <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Right Column') ) : ?> 
  <?php endif; ?>
</div> <!-- end #first-col -->
  
 <div id="last-col"> 
  <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Left Column') ) : ?> 
  <?php endif; ?>
 </div> <!-- end #last-col -->

Comment: In footer.php   <div class="container clearfix">
  <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer') ) : ?> 
  <?php endif; ?>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>

Comment: there is no register function in functions.php

Comment: I tried to add this code into my theme but it is not working, please suggest .

Comment: I broke it down into 3 widget areas for you left, center, and right.  And added some basic css structure.  Follow the directions exactly as written it works.  I always test my code before I submit an answer.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am really grateful to you for your help I tried the new solution but still it gives me the same error I have followed your steps carefully but after completing the first step it gave me error I have uploaded the theme files here http://hotfile.com/dl/71610238/e022ca0/SimplePress.zip.html  Please if possible edit theses file, I am really grateful to you for your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

codex it's not outdated http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar, this might help you.